# How can this Postgresql be solved

Tags: postgresql

I am new in Postgrsql. I am trying to Insert few records in a column. I have a where condition.

I am trying the following code

```
INSERT INTO table_name(column_one)
    VALUES ('1000')
    (SELECT * from table_name WHERE column_two = 'boo') ;
```

Here is the table structure

column_One||Column_two||Column_three

One||aaa||xxx

two||bbb||xxx

three||ccc||xxx

four||ddd||yyy

five||eee||yyy

Now I want to change the all the value of column_two to 'ttt' where column_three = 'xxx'

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are you trying to do? What are the columns in the `table_name` table? In which table do you want to insert it to? currently it looks like you are trying to insert data from a table into itself.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: This belongs to StackOverflow or ServerFault. 

Comment: Or [**DBA**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have said that you want to update all the value of column_two to 'ttt' where column_three = 'xxx'

As such this has nothing to do specifically with GIS, and doesn't fall within the scope of this site. However let me give you an answer.

This is a very basic SQL Query, and I suggest that you learn at-least the basics of SQL. It is very easy to mess up your database, with a small mistake in your query, and if you can't read, or can't frame even basic queries, you are in for a bit of trouble.

The simple query to do this would be :

`Update table_name set column_two='ttt' where column_three='xxx'`

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with Devdatta Tengshe, we need more details.

You have two choice :
A. You can insert a value in your table (1 record) with this query :

```
INSERT INTO table_name(column_one) VALUES ('1000');
```

It will create a line in your table (table_name) with the string '1000'.

B. You can insert a set of lines from another table (for exemple table_name_2), with this query :

```
  INSERT INTO table_name(column_one) 
    ( SELECT column_a FROM table_name_2 );
  -- With a WHERE CLAUSE :
  INSERT INTO table_name(column_one) 
    ( SELECT column_a FROM table_name_2 WHERE column_b = 'boo');
```

It will insert all lines from table_name_2 into table_name